# Best way to use a dll from an ASP script

Tags: security, dll, asp-classic, activex, intranet

I'm writing some ASP code to service requests from a simple HTML form on my company's intranet. The code needs to call methods from a (COM) dll. I'm using the code:

```
myObject = Server.CreateObject("myDLL.myClass")
```

but it's giving an error at this line. I'm not sure if the dll is registered on the server, but I suspect it may not be. I'm not sure how to find this out.

If it's not registered, is it possible/best practice to:

1. Use the dll without registering it on the server (I have the .dll file);
2. Remotely register the dll safely using ASP code; or
3. Do I need to contact the IT dept to get it registered?

I'm worried that option 2 might freak the IT department out and also possibly break something - but I have a deadline and it's unlikely that they will get around to registering anything before then.

**Is there any way I can use the dll without involving them, purely with ASP?**

I've also got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711602/activex-control-in-ie-intranet-zone-blocked-without-a-prompt) open regarding running the dll on the client's computers by embedding in the intranet form, *which is my preferred method if it's possible.* It's the same dll, and it's already registered on all clients' machines but so far I've been unable to get it passed the IE intranet security settings.

ANY help/comments/suggestions on this or [my other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711602/activex-control-in-ie-intranet-zone-blocked-without-a-prompt) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to register the DLL AFAIK, either with a setup program that does it, or manually with regsvr32 (or similar)